# Hi everyone. Could anyone help me with this Power query problem

Tags: excel, powerquery

I have a table as indicated below where the Category column could have multiple categories each with its own scale which is shown in the Value column. I would like to create a new column that multiplies all the values where the item column does not equal 'scale' by the corresponding scale value that matches its category.
In the example below: if Category = A then multiply the value by 10

I've been stuck with this for a while and would truly appreciate any help.

Note - there are hundreds of categories and each one could have a different value. In the actual data, the category is a date and for each of those dates, there is a corresponding scale value that the remainder of the data that matches that date will need to be multiplied by.

Original Table

| Item | Category | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Scale | A | 10 |
| Scale | B | 5 |
| Scale | C | 2 |
| Apples | A | 100 |
| Fruit | B | 10 |
| Car | C | 15 |
| Pear | A | 20 |
| Lemon | B | 5 |

New Column added

| Item | Category | Value | Calc_Val |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Scale | A | 10 | null |
| Scale | B | 5 | null |
| Scale | C | 2 | null |
| Apples | A | 100 | 1000 |
| Fruit | B | 10 | 50 |
| Car | C | 15 | 30 |
| Pear | A | 20 | 200 |
| Lemon | B | 5 | 25 |

Comment: And where is your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your first table is named `Table1`, create a new table, `Table2`, via

```
let
    Source = Table1,
    #"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(Source, each ([Item] = "Scale"))
in
    #"Filtered Rows"
```

Then create a third table, via

```
let
  Source = Table.NestedJoin(
    Table1, 
    {"Category"}, 
    Table2, 
    {"Category"}, 
    "Table2", 
    JoinKind.LeftOuter
  ), 
  #"Expanded Table2" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(Source, "Table2", {"Value"}, {"Table2.Value"}), 
  #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(
    #"Expanded Table2", 
    "Custom", 
    each if [Item] = "Scale" then null else [Value] * [Table2.Value]
  )
in
  #"Added Custom"
```

Comment: Hi @Jos, thanks for the help.

I'm trying to implement your solution but the first part seems to create a product of all the values for that category. So in the table above say that was another row with

Comment: @Ohwh But the Calc_Val column in your second table are your expected results, no?

Comment: I added a few more rows to provide better clarity. The first table in your solution gives me a product of all the values associated with that category. What I'm looking for is each row value where the item <> 'scale' to be multiplied by the category value identified by the term 'scale' in the item row.

I can post the actual file I'm working on if that helps and once again thanks for the help. :)

Comment: @Ohwh I'm not Ron! Also, I'm still confused about the purpose of your Calc_Val column, which IS including 'Scale' items in the product.

Comment: my apologies for that. The scale row identifies the value that needs to be applied for each category in the rows where item <> 'scale'. The result of which goes into the calc-Value column. I edited the table in the question for more clarity.

Comment: @Ohwh Thanks, understand now, I think. Have amended.

Comment: Thank you so much, this solves it.

Comment: You're welcome!

Answer (score 0):

Have a lookup table with each category and the matching multiplication factor, then use the following formula:

```
=C2*INDEX(H$2:H$5,MATCH(A2,G$2:G$5,0))
```

[image]